# How to do theoretical calculation of S parameters

Tags: s-parameters, ads

I created a test bench for bond wire in ADS EM simulator and got the following graph in the picture I attached. I'm trying to compare the values which I got in ADS with theoretical one. But I'm confused how to do calculation of S-parameters in a two port network.

Kindly help me to calculate the S parameters and compare with the practical one.
[image]

Comment: something like [this](http://cas.web.cern.ch/cas/denmark-2010/lectures/caspers-s-parameters.pdf)? The first hit when I googled 'calculate s-parameters of series impedance'.

Answer (score 3):

The long answer is set up the problem like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZi2uK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now calculate the forward and reverse-travelling waves at each of the ports. This gives you \$S_{11}\$ and \$S_{21}\$.

Then hook up the generator on the other side of the device and calculate the forward and reverse travelling waves again to get \$S_{12}\$ and \$S_{22}\$.

But since you are already using ADS, there is an easier way: Hook up your device model between S parameter ports and simulate it. This will also make it easier to make ADS draw a graph comparing the simple model with the more complex model.

If your "theoretical" model is a simple combination of R, L, and C elements, you could even use the ADS optimizer to tune the theoretical model to match the phenomenological model (or vice versa), or to match some measurement data.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve for S parameters is to use ABCD parameters.

For a series connection you would have :

|1  R|

|0  1|

For a parallel connection you would have :

|1   0|

|1/R 1|

After calculating the ABCD parameters you can use the general formulas to get the S parameters.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Mnm2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To solve for the S-Parameters of the circuit we can use the above procedure as :

[image]

The only thing you need to know is how to model the bond wire you are using i.e the RLC parameters so that you can make your circuit model.

Comment: They do use latex to write down equations on this site